# gwt layout panels to match browser screen size not working

Tags: gwt, layout, cross-browser, screen, dockpanel

trying just to get app layout to fit whole browser screen, only works in IE. I have a DockLayoutPanel and a HorizontalPanel added to the Dock center:

```
             DockLayoutPanel layout = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
             HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
             layout.add(hp);
             RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
             rp.add(layout);
```

On chrome and firefox the displayed screen is "too big", only see part of it. In GWT development mode, it works fine in all browsers.I've tried setting Dock and Horizontal panel sizes explicitly, based on Window.getClientWidth/Height, but it has no effect. I thought that just making a DockLayoutPanel and adding it to a RootLayoutPanel guarantees matching to the browser client screen area...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think mixing `HoritonalPanels` with `LayoutPanels` (like `DockLayoutPanel`) is the best thing you can do (see [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Standards) for more details).
Why don't you use `LayoutPanels` inside your `DockLayoutPanel`?

Or alternatively use a `FlowPanel` with `float:left` like explained in the docs.

Comment: there's example code in javadoc for RootLayoutPanel, which I tried to reproduce (see below) and it didn't solve the problem:

Comment: there's example code in the javadoc for RootLayoutPanel which I tried to reproduce (see below), with no effect:

Comment: there's example code in javadoc for RootLayoutPanel, which I tried to reproduce (see below) and it didn't solve the problem:                    LayoutPanel lp = new LayoutPanel();  lp.add(navigation); lp.add(content); lp.setWidgetLeftWidth(navigation, 0, Style.Unit.PCT, 25, Style.Unit.PCT);  // Left panel
lp.setWidgetRightWidth(content, 0, Style.Unit.PCT, 75, Style.Unit.PCT); // Right panel
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(lp);     same results, but works in IE